# not downloading the complete package in cloud formation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

When I am trying to download the rpm through wget , i am getting incomplete package downloaded on my machine. What can be the reason?
The package is around 300 MB , and it is only downloading it upto 30-40 MB.
Here is my user data .

```
            "UserData": {
                "Fn::Base64": {
                    "Fn::Join": [
                        "",
                        [
                            "#!/bin/bash -v \n",
                            "growpart /dev/xvdb 1 2> /tmp/growpart.out \n",
                            "pvcreate /dev/xvdf \n",
                            "vgcreate var_opt /dev/xvdf \n",
                            "lvcreate -l 25595 -n var_opscode var_opt \n",
                            "mkfs.ext4 /dev/var_opt/var_opscode \n",
                            "echo '/dev/var_opt/var_opscode       /var/opt/opscode-analytics    ext4    defaults    1  2' >> /etc/fstab \n",
                            "mkdir –p /var/opt/opscode-analytics \n",
                            "mount /dev/var_opt/var_opscode /var/opt/opscode-analytics \n",
                            "chmod 755 /var/opt/opscode-analytics \n",  
                            "reboot \n",              
                            "cd /tmp\n",
                            "wget -O AnalyticsPackage.rpm ",
                            {
                                "Ref": "NexusAnalyticsTar"
                            },
                            " \n",
                            "sleep 100 \n",
                            "rpm -Uvh AnalyticsPackage.rpm \n",
                            "sleep 100 \n",            
                            "echo package installed \n",
                            "\n"
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

THis was resolved as I was trying to reboot the server in the middle.
It is resolved now after I made the reboot as the last step.